# Writing $f(x)=h(x)\cdot(x-\alpha)^m$ when $\alpha$ is a root of multiplicity $m$

Tags: real-analysis, analyticity

Let $f$ be a real function, and $\alpha \in \Bbb R$ a root of $f$ of multiplicity $m$. Under what conditions can I write $f(x)=h(x)\cdot(x-\alpha)^m$, where $h(\alpha)\neq 0$ ?

I know it's true if $f$ is a polynomial, or when $f$ is an analytic function. But is it true in other cases as well?

Comment: The definition of having a root of multiplicity $m$ could be your conclusion. In that case there is nothing to prove. Are you using other definition of having a root of multiplicity $m$? Which one?

Comment: Is there a different definition?

Comment: @conditionalMethod according to my definition, $m = \min\{n\in \Bbb Z_+ : f^{(n)}(\alpha)=0 \}$.

Comment: @lhf I do want $h$ to be smooth

Comment: @user401516, so $f \in C^\infty$ ?

Comment: Please edit the question and add all definitions and hypotheses you need.

Comment: @lhf Not neccessarily

Comment: That's exactly what I am asking, what do I need to assume for it to be true? I will edit the definition of multiplicity

Comment: If your function has derivatives at $\alpha$ of order up to $m+k$, then $f(x)=f(\alpha)+f'(\alpha)(x-\alpha)/1!+...+f^{(m+k)}(\alpha)(x-\alpha)^{m+k}/(m+k)!+g(x)$, where $g(x)/(x-\alpha)^{m+k}\to0$ as $x\to\alpha$. If $f^{(n)}(\alpha)=0$, for $n=0,1,...,m$, then $f(x)=f^{(m+1)}(\alpha)(x-\alpha)^{m+1}/(m+1)!+...f^{(m+k)}(\alpha)(x-\alpha)^{m+k}/(m+k)!+g(x)$. So $f(x)=(x-\alpha)^mh(x)$. However, the $h$, as you see, can only be shown to have derivatives at $\alpha$ up to order $k$. So, some differentiability can be lost.

Comment: @conditionalMethod Why does $h$ have derivatives at $\alpha$ up to order $k$?

Comment: Its value at $\alpha$ is zero. Therefore, its derivative is the limit of $h(x)/(x-\alpha)$, but this limit is known to be zero too. So, the derivative is zero at $\alpha$. Apply Taylor to it and induction on $k$.